# C# Force all xml Namespaces to be added in the Root element when serializing an object

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

By using xsd2code I've generated from my xml schema files a classfile. I use this class file to create an object and fill the required properties. When done I want to serialize this object into an xml message.
This is all working fine, with the exception of the layout of the message. Because I use a common complex type and extend that type depending on a condition a part of the elements will have namespace1 while the others have namespace2. The serializer adds by default the namespace on the element causing the message to be unnecessary big and not easy to read for a human.

This can be solved by manually adding the required namespaces to an XmlNamespacesSerializer List and adding that list to the XmlSerializer call. Because the serializer is used for more than 1 type I cannot hardcode the xmlnamespaces into it. The Xml namespaces must be available from the type because the serializer is using them. so the question is how do I get all the Xml namespaces required for this message from the type that is given to the xml serializer?
I've tried using

```
GetType().GetCustomAttributes<XmlRootAttribute>();
```

And

```
GetType().GetCustomAttributes<XmlTypeAttribute>();
```

but those only return the attributes from the given type and not the underlying used types.

To give an idea what I have and what I want this is an example

vb3.xsd it imports 3 schema's (common, boat and car)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/vb3" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/vb3" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/vb3" xmlns:com="http://tempuri.org/CommonTypes" xmlns:boat="http://tempuri.org/BoatType" xmlns:car="http://tempuri.org/CarType" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/CommonTypes" schemaLocation="Common.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/CarType" schemaLocation="CarType.xsd"/>
    <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/BoatType" schemaLocation="BoatType.xsd"/>
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Input" type="com:CommonType"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Common.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/CommonTypes" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/CommonTypes" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:complexType name="CommonType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Make" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Model" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Car.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/CarType" xmlns:com="http://tempuri.org/CommonTypes" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/CarType" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/CommonTypes" schemaLocation="Common.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="CarType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="com:CommonType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Airbags" type="xs:boolean"/>
                    <xs:element name="EningeSize" type="xs:decimal"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Boat.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BoatType" xmlns:com="http://tempuri.org/CommonTypes" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/BoatType" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <xs:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/CommonTypes" schemaLocation="Common.xsd"/>
    <xs:complexType name="BoatType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="com:CommonType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Motorized" type="xs:boolean"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Xsd2code generates a class from this (for the example I'm using the generated Serial method from Xsd2Code in the actual program it is not there). (the complete class it too big for this form so I picked parts from it that I think could be relevant).

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xsd2Code", "5.18")]
    [Serializable]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://tempuri.org/vb3")]
    [XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/vb3", IsNullable=false)]
    public partial class root
    {
        #region Private fields
        private CommonType _input;
        private static XmlSerializer _serializer;
        #endregion
        
        public root()
        {
            _input = new CommonType();
        }
        
        public CommonType Input
        {
            get
            {
                return _input;
            }
            set
            {
                _input = value;
            }
        }
        
        private static XmlSerializer SerializerXML
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_serializer == null))
                {
                    _serializer = new XmlSerializerFactory().CreateSerializer(typeof(root));
                }
                return _serializer;
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Test whether Input should be serialized
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool ShouldSerializeInput()
        {
            return (_input != null);
        }
        
        #region Serialize/Deserialize
        /// <summary>
        /// Serialize root object
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>XML value</returns>
        public virtual string Serial()
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = null;
            MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
            try
            {
                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
                System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings);
                SerializerXML.Serialize(xmlWriter, this);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((streamReader != null))
                {
                    streamReader.Dispose();
                }
                if ((memoryStream != null))
                {
                    memoryStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }

...

[XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(BoatType))]
    [XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(CarType))]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xsd2Code", "5.18")]
    [Serializable]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/CommonTypes")]
    public partial class CommonType
    {
        #region Private fields
        private string _make;
        private string _model;
        private static XmlSerializer _serializer;
        #endregion
        
        public string Make
        {
            get
            {
                return _make;
            }
            set
            {
                _make = value;
            }
        }
        
        public string Model
        {
            get
            {
                return _model;
            }
            set
            {
                _model = value;
            }
        }
        
        private static XmlSerializer SerializerXML
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_serializer == null))
                {
                    _serializer = new XmlSerializerFactory().CreateSerializer(typeof(CommonType));
                }
                return _serializer;
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Test whether Make should be serialized
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool ShouldSerializeMake()
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Make);
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Test whether Model should be serialized
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool ShouldSerializeModel()
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model);
        }
        
        #region Serialize/Deserialize
        /// <summary>
        /// Serialize CommonType object
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>XML value</returns>
        public virtual string Serial()
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = null;
            MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
            try
            {
                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
                System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings);
                SerializerXML.Serialize(xmlWriter, this);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((streamReader != null))
                {
                    streamReader.Dispose();
                }
                if ((memoryStream != null))
                {
                    memoryStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
    
...

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xsd2Code", "5.18")]
    [Serializable]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://tempuri.org/CarType")]
    public partial class CarType : CommonType
    {
        #region Private fields
        private bool _shouldSerializeEningeSize;
        private bool _shouldSerializeAirbags;
        private bool _airbags;
        private decimal _eningeSize;
        private static XmlSerializer _serializer;
        #endregion
        
        public bool Airbags
        {
            get
            {
                return _airbags;
            }
            set
            {
                _airbags = value;
                _shouldSerializeAirbags = true;
            }
        }
        
        public decimal EningeSize
        {
            get
            {
                return _eningeSize;
            }
            set
            {
                _eningeSize = value;
                _shouldSerializeEningeSize = true;
            }
        }
        
        private static XmlSerializer SerializerXML
        {
            get
            {
                if ((_serializer == null))
                {
                    _serializer = new XmlSerializerFactory().CreateSerializer(typeof(CarType));
                }
                return _serializer;
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Test whether Airbags should be serialized
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool ShouldSerializeAirbags()
        {
            if (_shouldSerializeAirbags)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return (_airbags != default(bool));
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Test whether EningeSize should be serialized
        /// </summary>
        public virtual bool ShouldSerializeEningeSize()
        {
            if (_shouldSerializeEningeSize)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return (_eningeSize != default(decimal));
        }
        
        public virtual string Serial()
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = null;
            MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
            try
            {
                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
                System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings);
                SerializerXML.Serialize(xmlWriter, this);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((streamReader != null))
                {
                    streamReader.Dispose();
                }
                if ((memoryStream != null))
                {
                    memoryStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

and the result will be this. As you can see the make and model element both have the common namepsace defined in the element itself.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns="http://tempuri.org/vb3">
    <Input xmlns:q1="http://tempuri.org/CarType"
           xsi:type="q1:CarType">
        <Make xmlns="http://tempuri.org/CommonTypes">Ford</Make>
        <Model xmlns="http://tempuri.org/CommonTypes">Mustang</Model>
        <q1:Airbags>true</q1:Airbags>
        <q1:EningeSize>5.7</q1:EningeSize>
    </Input>
</root>
```

By adding the namespaces to the serial method like this

```
/// <summary>
        /// Serialize root object
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>XML value</returns>
        public virtual string Serial()
        {
            StreamReader streamReader = null;
            MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
            try
            {
                var nslist = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
                nslist.Add("tns", "http://tempuri.org/vb3");
                nslist.Add("com", "http://tempuri.org/CommonTypes");
                nslist.Add("car", "http://tempuri.org/CarType");
                nslist.Add("boat", "http://tempuri.org/BoatType");

                memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
                System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings);
                SerializerXML.Serialize(xmlWriter, this,nslist);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream);
                return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            finally
            {
                if ((streamReader != null))
                {
                    streamReader.Dispose();
                }
                if ((memoryStream != null))
                {
                    memoryStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
        }
```

the output will look like this, far more readable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tns:root xmlns:car="http://tempuri.org/CarType" xmlns:com="http://tempuri.org/CommonTypes" xmlns:boat="http://tempuri.org/BoatType" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/vb3">
    <tns:Input p5:type="car:CarType" xmlns:p5="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <com:Make>Ford</com:Make>
        <com:Model>Mustang</com:Model>
        <car:Airbags>true</car:Airbags>
        <car:EningeSize>5.7</car:EningeSize>
    </tns:Input>
</tns:root>
```

Comment: I face the same issue. Did you contact the xsd2code support?

Comment: No I did not. The xsd2code serializer is correct, what I wanted to achieve is just a presentation problem. I decided to write my own serialize extension method that has an additional parameter to move all namespaces to the root. Because I have several xml messages with different namespaces I did not want to hardcode them into the method. So when i serialize the message I take the expensive route to parse the xml message into a xdoc and use xpath navigator to loop through it and make a unique list of all used namespaces. that list I add in a second serialize to get the actual message.